# Get index of matching value in List using LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I would like to be able to run a LINQ query on a BindingList(Of T) that returns the *indexes* where a list object member is equal to a particular value.

say I have a list of simple objects of class widget:

```
Public Class widget
    Public Property foo As Integer
    Public Property bar As String
End Class
Dim widgetList As BindingList(Of widget)
```

I'd like to be able to query the list some thing like the below:

```
Dim test As Integer = 5
Dim index = (From i In widgetList
             Where i.foo = test
             Select i.index).First
```

Such that index contains the index of the first listItem where widgetList.Item(index).foo = 5. What is the best way to do this? (Or should I even be using LINQ)

I have seen several C# methods to do this but Im not sufficiently au fait with C# to understand how to use them in VB

Comment: As far as linq is considered, c# and vb syntax are mostly the same. About your question: in title you're asking about matching valueS (means that you're expecting more that one match) but in the code you're using .First, which means you're taking only first item from selected results.

Comment: So I did - edited to remove plural. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to achieve with LINQ by using the fluent syntax since there's an overloaded version of the `Select` extension method that lets you get the index of the items.

Try this approach:

```
Dim test As Integer = 5
Dim query = widgetList.Select(Function(o,i) New With { .Widget = o, .Index = i}) _
                      .FirstOrDefault(Function(item) item.Widget.Foo = test)
If query Is Nothing
    Console.WriteLine("Item not found")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Item found at index {0}", query.Index)
End If
```

In the `Select` I'm projecting the Widget as is, using `o`, and the `i` parameter represents the index. Next I use `FirstOrDefault` with a predicate to evaluate `Foo` (you could've used `Where` followed by `FirstOrDefault`, but this is shorter). You should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of just `First` in case none of the items are found; `FirstOrDefault` will return null if nothing is found, whereas `First` would throw an exception. That's why the next step is to check the result and make sure it isn't null.

Answer (score 1):

I have also found a working solution as below, though I am not sure if this is any better or worse than the other answers.

```
Dim index = Enumerable.Range(0, widgetList.Count) _
            .Where(Function(i) widgetList.Item(i).foo = test) _
            .First
```

Comment: That works but you've introduced a new collection to compare to your original collection, which *probably* performs slower. From a readability standpoint, it's clearer to work against the original collection. From a performance standpoint the code has to generate `n` items in the range to evaluate the query.

Comment: @AhmadMageed, Good man, thanks, I'll switch to your answer so :)